# Unable to disable F5 key in IE8

Tags: javascript

I want to disable F5 key in my web application. I am using the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onkeydown=function(e) {
               if (e.keyCode === 116 ) {
                       alert("This action is not allowed");
                       e.keyCode = 0;
                       e.returnValue = false;                  
                       return false;
                   }

               }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p> F5 Test IE8</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code works fine in Chrome but in IE8 it is not working. On pressing F5 the page gets refreshed on IE8. I have tried using e.preventDefault(), but nothing works. Any help??

Comment: For what purpose?  They could also use Ctrl/Cmd + R or press the refresh button.

Comment: I think another(may be better) option is to check if user is navigating away from page (example: refresh) and ask for confirmation.

Comment: Don't tamper with default browser functionality.

Comment: This happens at the browser level, not the DOM level.  Basically, you can't do that, even if there were *any possible* good reason to do so.

Comment: I agree with you John, but that's how the project's requirement is

Answer (score 4):

Try next code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.onkeydown=function(e) {
    e=e||window.event;
    if (e.keyCode === 116 ) {
      e.keyCode = 0;
      alert("This action is not allowed");
      if(e.preventDefault)e.preventDefault();
      else e.returnValue = false;
      return false;
    }
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p> F5 Test IE8</p>
</body>
</html>
```

- You must use `document` object instead of `window` object. In IE8 `window` object does not support `onkeydown`.
- You must use `e=e||window.event;` code line because in IE8- when event registered as `element.on...` no parameter is received into event handler function (`e` from your example is `undefined`);

Comment: Thanks Andrew for the help. With the code snippet posted by you I am getting the alert message but the page is still getting refreshed on IE8. Is there any way to stop the page from getting refreshed when F5 is pressed?

Comment: @Himanshu Saraswat, Sorry, I lose one code line `e.keyCode = 0;` See updated answer. I checked it in IE8 and Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Tested in IE8, firefox and chrome:

```
document.onkeydown=function(e) {
    var event = window.event || e;
    if (event.keyCode == 116) {
        event.keyCode = 0;
        alert("This action is not allowed");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Also see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/BwLdX/3/show/).

Comment: In my example you had to focus the result frame first to test the script. I've updated the link to prevent this. To see the source again, remove the `/show/` in the url of the link.

Comment: Thanks a million scessor. Your code worked. But I also noticed that if I am testing for multiple key strokes (F5,Backspace or ctrl+R), F5 must be the first key to be tested else by the time the code is processed it reaches the onbeforeunload event. Thanks for the help