# Can't prevent IE8 re-post warning with client side-code

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, web, internet-explorer-8

I'm using asp.net webforms, so every server control generates **post** request on click. If I try to reload page with F5 or Ctrl+R after that request, browser by default shows re-post warning.

To avoid this behavior in IE 7-* I tried this solution: *[Unable to disable F5 key in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222116/unable-to-disable-f5-key-in-ie8)*

But there is still warning in IE8 after **post**, whereas after **get** request all right. 
How to deal with it?

Comment: Look up "Post redirect Get (PRG)" pattern. Perhaps it would be helpful

Comment: I can't override asp.net behavior in that case.

Comment: If you Redirect to the same page after a Post, this is avoided. Of course, you may want that only if you don't plan to preserve the data.

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't disable the F5 key or the browser back button as this is breaks the user mental model of how the browser works (and this is a bad thing).

The post warning is important because you really are POSTING the data back to the server (if this was after posting a record to a shopping cart) then you would submit the purchase again or add the previously added record to the database again.

It would be better to provide them with a clear and obvious way for them to get updates to the page when then require them.

#### A suggestion

If you just want to refresh the page to see the contents of an updated table or list or to get the latest status after the post then you could provide a button or link on the page that the user can click that preforms a AJAX get for the information that you requires and then just update the part of the screen that you need to redisplay.

You could also also do this with a SetTimeout so that the page / data updates in the background without the need for the user to click on a button or link.